# Error al instalar MySQL en Debian 11

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, debian

Trate de instalar MySQL en Debian 11
para eso quize instalar el paquete `mariadb-server` que ya viene incluido en los repositorios de debian, no quiero importar ningun otro repositorio

```sh
root@servidor:~# apt install mariadb-server
```

Pero me sale un error de que no se pudo desempaquetar uno de los paquetes que necesita la instalacion

```sh
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-xIob5H/00-mariadb-server-10.5_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

En un punto de la instalacion trató de desempaquetar mariadb-server-10.5 pero no pudo

```sh
Preparando para desempaquetar .../00-mariadb-server-10.5_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
useradd: no se pudo abrir /etc/shadow
adduser: `/sbin/useradd -d /nonexistent -g mysql -s /bin/false -u 107 mysql' devolvió el código de error 1. Saliendo.
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-xIob5H/00-mariadb-server-10.5_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 el subproceso nuevo paquete mariadb-server-10.5 script pre-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
```

Este es el bash completo

```sh
root@servidor:~# apt update && apt upgrade
Obj:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Obj:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Des:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [39.4 kB]
Obj:4 https://packages.sury.org/php bullseye InRelease
Descargados 39.4 kB en 1s (34.9 kB/s)              
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Todos los paquetes están actualizados.
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Calculando la actualización... Hecho
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.

root@servidor:~# apt install mariadb-server
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  galera-4 libaio1 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libclone-perl libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mariadb-perl libdbi-perl libencode-locale-perl libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl
  libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmariadb3 libsnappy1v5 libterm-readkey-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mariadb-client-10.5 mariadb-client-core-10.5 mariadb-common
  mariadb-server-10.5 mariadb-server-core-10.5 mysql-common rsync socat
Paquetes sugeridos:
  libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libsql-statement-perl libdata-dump-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl libwww-perl mailx mariadb-test netcat-openbsd
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  galera-4 libaio1 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libclone-perl libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mariadb-perl libdbi-perl libencode-locale-perl libfcgi-bin libfcgi-perl libfcgi0ldbl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl
  libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmariadb3 libsnappy1v5 libterm-readkey-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mariadb-client-10.5 mariadb-client-core-10.5 mariadb-common
  mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.5 mariadb-server-core-10.5 mysql-common rsync socat
0 actualizados, 33 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
Se necesita descargar 16.7 MB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 154 MB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
Des:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.8+1.0.7 [7 464 B]
Des:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mariadb-common all 1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1 [36.3 kB]
Des:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 galera-4 amd64 26.4.9-0+deb11u1 [796 kB]
Des:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libdbi-perl amd64 1.643-3+b1 [780 kB]
Des:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libconfig-inifiles-perl all 3.000003-1 [52.1 kB]
Des:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libmariadb3 amd64 1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1 [175 kB]
Des:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mariadb-client-core-10.5 amd64 1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1 [779 kB]
Des:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mariadb-client-10.5 amd64 1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1 [1 496 kB]
Des:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libaio1 amd64 0.3.112-9 [12.5 kB]
Des:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsnappy1v5 amd64 1.1.8-1 [17.9 kB]
Des:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mariadb-server-core-10.5 amd64 1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1 [6 589 kB]
Des:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 rsync amd64 3.2.3-4+deb11u1 [396 kB]
Des:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 socat amd64 1.7.4.1-3 [370 kB]
Des:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mariadb-server-10.5 amd64 1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1 [4 226 kB]
Des:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libhtml-tagset-perl all 3.20-4 [13.0 kB]
Des:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 liburi-perl all 5.08-1 [90.6 kB]
Des:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libhtml-parser-perl amd64 3.75-1+b1 [105 kB]
Des:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libcgi-pm-perl all 4.51-1 [224 kB]
Des:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libfcgi0ldbl amd64 2.4.2-2 [26.1 kB]
Des:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libfcgi-perl amd64 0.79+ds-2 [27.6 kB]
Des:21 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libcgi-fast-perl all 1:2.15-1 [12.1 kB]
Des:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libclone-perl amd64 0.45-1+b1 [15.4 kB]
Des:23 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libdbd-mariadb-perl amd64 1.21-3 [110 kB]
Des:24 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libencode-locale-perl all 1.05-1.1 [13.2 kB]
Des:25 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libfcgi-bin amd64 2.4.2-2 [12.9 kB]
Des:26 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libhtml-template-perl all 2.97-1.1 [66.2 kB]
Des:27 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libtimedate-perl all 2.3300-2 [39.3 kB]
Des:28 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libhttp-date-perl all 6.05-1 [10.4 kB]
Des:29 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libio-html-perl all 1.004-2 [16.1 kB]
Des:30 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 liblwp-mediatypes-perl all 6.04-1 [19.9 kB]
Des:31 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libhttp-message-perl all 6.28-1 [79.6 kB]
Des:32 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libterm-readkey-perl amd64 2.38-1+b2 [27.8 kB]
Des:33 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 mariadb-server all 1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1 [34.9 kB]
Descargados 16.7 MB en 0s (39.9 MB/s) 
Extrayendo plantillas para los paquetes: 100%
Preconfigurando paquetes ...
Seleccionando el paquete mysql-common previamente no seleccionado.
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 37849 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../00-mysql-common_5.8+1.0.7_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando mysql-common (5.8+1.0.7) ...
Seleccionando el paquete mariadb-common previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../01-mariadb-common_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando mariadb-common (1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete galera-4 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../02-galera-4_26.4.9-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando galera-4 (26.4.9-0+deb11u1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libdbi-perl:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../03-libdbi-perl_1.643-3+b1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libdbi-perl:amd64 (1.643-3+b1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libconfig-inifiles-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../04-libconfig-inifiles-perl_3.000003-1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libconfig-inifiles-perl (3.000003-1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libmariadb3:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../05-libmariadb3_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libmariadb3:amd64 (1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete mariadb-client-core-10.5 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../06-mariadb-client-core-10.5_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando mariadb-client-core-10.5 (1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete mariadb-client-10.5 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../07-mariadb-client-10.5_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando mariadb-client-10.5 (1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libaio1:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../08-libaio1_0.3.112-9_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libaio1:amd64 (0.3.112-9) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libsnappy1v5:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../09-libsnappy1v5_1.1.8-1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libsnappy1v5:amd64 (1.1.8-1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete mariadb-server-core-10.5 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../10-mariadb-server-core-10.5_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando mariadb-server-core-10.5 (1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete rsync previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../11-rsync_3.2.3-4+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando rsync (3.2.3-4+deb11u1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete socat previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../12-socat_1.7.4.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando socat (1.7.4.1-3) ...
Configurando mysql-common (5.8+1.0.7) ...
update-alternatives: utilizando /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback para proveer /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) en modo automático
Configurando mariadb-common (1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1) ...
update-alternatives: utilizando /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf para proveer /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) en modo automático
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 38320 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../00-mariadb-server-10.5_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
useradd: no se pudo abrir /etc/shadow
adduser: `/sbin/useradd -d /nonexistent -g mysql -s /bin/false -u 107 mysql' devolvió el código de error 1. Saliendo.
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-xIob5H/00-mariadb-server-10.5_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 el subproceso nuevo paquete mariadb-server-10.5 script pre-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Seleccionando el paquete libhtml-tagset-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../01-libhtml-tagset-perl_3.20-4_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-4) ...
Seleccionando el paquete liburi-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../02-liburi-perl_5.08-1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando liburi-perl (5.08-1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libhtml-parser-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../03-libhtml-parser-perl_3.75-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libhtml-parser-perl (3.75-1+b1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libcgi-pm-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../04-libcgi-pm-perl_4.51-1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libcgi-pm-perl (4.51-1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libfcgi0ldbl:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../05-libfcgi0ldbl_2.4.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libfcgi0ldbl:amd64 (2.4.2-2) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libfcgi-perl:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../06-libfcgi-perl_0.79+ds-2_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libfcgi-perl:amd64 (0.79+ds-2) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libcgi-fast-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../07-libcgi-fast-perl_1%3a2.15-1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libclone-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../08-libclone-perl_0.45-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libclone-perl (0.45-1+b1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libdbd-mariadb-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../09-libdbd-mariadb-perl_1.21-3_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libdbd-mariadb-perl (1.21-3) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libencode-locale-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../10-libencode-locale-perl_1.05-1.1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1.1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libfcgi-bin previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../11-libfcgi-bin_2.4.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libfcgi-bin (2.4.2-2) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libhtml-template-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../12-libhtml-template-perl_2.97-1.1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libtimedate-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../13-libtimedate-perl_2.3300-2_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libtimedate-perl (2.3300-2) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libhttp-date-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../14-libhttp-date-perl_6.05-1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libhttp-date-perl (6.05-1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libio-html-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../15-libio-html-perl_1.004-2_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libio-html-perl (1.004-2) ...
Seleccionando el paquete liblwp-mediatypes-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../16-liblwp-mediatypes-perl_6.04-1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.04-1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libhttp-message-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../17-libhttp-message-perl_6.28-1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libhttp-message-perl (6.28-1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libterm-readkey-perl previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../18-libterm-readkey-perl_2.38-1+b2_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libterm-readkey-perl (2.38-1+b2) ...
Seleccionando el paquete mariadb-server previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../19-mariadb-server_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando mariadb-server (1:10.5.12-0+deb11u1) ...
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-xIob5H/00-mariadb-server-10.5_1%3a10.5.12-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Qué sale en la salida de este comando? `ls -l /etc/shadow`. Agrégalo como info de la pregunta, plis.

Answer (score 0):

aun no me queda muy claro el origen de problema...., pero podrias probar purgando lo que hayas instalado de mysql, y volver a probar con estos comandos

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove mysql-common
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

saludos.